# Passing values between Android activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I understand that the theme is beat up, but still I could not find an answer for my case.

I have an `activity1` running.

I launch `activity2` from `activity1`:

```
Intent newIntent1 = new Intent(this,activity2.class);
startActivity(newIntent1);
```

I get some values in activity2 and I need to return them as a string to the activity1.

If I use:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this,activity1.class);
newIntent.PutExtra("dataname",SomeString);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

I get `activity1` started once more. But I need to return `SomeString` to the original `activity1`  from `activity2`. So should I use something else instead of intent?

Comment: try - startActivityForResult();

Comment: You can use startActivityForResult() when start activity2 and use setResult() from Activity2. and get in onActivityResult in Activity1. Use this link. http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your activity2 as `startActivityForResult` and use `setResult()` method for sending data back from activity2 to activity1. In activity1 you will need to Override `onActivityResult` for Updating data from `activity2`

Try out as below:

Start Activity2 from Acivity1 as:

```
Intent intnt = new Intent(this,  activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(intnt, 1);
```

in **activity2** use **setResult** for sending data back :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("keyvalue","value_here")
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
finish();
```

and in **activity1** receive data as `onActivityResult`:

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
          String stredittext=data.getStringExtra("keyvalue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvote ??? Can you explain ? DownVoter do clearify the things before downvoting.

Comment: in this case: onActivityResult(requestCode = 1, resultCode=RESULT_OK, and what is data then?)

Comment: It will comes in `onActivityResult` as you pass the result back from your second activity to your first activity with the result code will be `RESULT_OK` if the data is successfully passed. @AndrejkaBarmalejka

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach will be declaring that String in main activity class(not in onCreate method) as static and access that string in as many activities you want referring it as
MainActivity.stringName in other activities and as
stringName in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing okay so far, you just need to request the values you have set

In your oncreate (in your case in your activity1)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {
        String value = extras.getString("dataname");
    }
}
```